# Multiples tareas en segundo plano en Android

Tags: java, android

me gustaria que me orienten en como correr varias tareas (funciones) en **segundo plano**, incluso cuando se cierra la app desde las apps recientes.

Por ejemplo:

- una tarea que verifique una URL cada 10 minutos (es una API de
  pronóstico metereológico)
- una tarea que verifique cada 1 minuto si se
  cumple una condición (ejemplo: recordatorios fijados por el usuario)
- etcetera.

Sé que Android Oreo impuso limitaciones a los servicios en segundo plano. La idea es que la app sea compatible desde la versión 5.0 a la más actual posible.

*Uso: Android Studio.*

Gracias desde ya!

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Rodriz, te comento que  tu pregunta cae dentro del rango de "demasiado amplia",  te sugiero revisar [ask], edita tu pregunta agregando lo que hayas tratado o investigado. No olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, saludos!-.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es usar Servicios, aqui te dejo la documentacion oficial. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=es-419
https://developer.android.com/training/best-background y este tutorial a mi me ayudo http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html